# OAuth 1.0 to Oauth 2.0 Migration - "Invalid Token"

Tags: google-oauth

I'm Attempting to perform migration on user oauth 1.0 tokens to oauth 2.0 tokens, by following the steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref?hl=en#migration).

Below is a sample of the call I'm making, redirected to my localhost.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 162
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.6.2 CPython/2.7.10 Darwin/14.1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="52494019971914196991439415494", oauth_timestamp="1439415494", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="xxxxx.com", oauth_token="x%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_signature="Da%2Bb0gFGyYT6AR2Xb5TAX5ynKQQ%3D"

client_secret=-FeCSEHzGADOt-3On5rE7Ghi&grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Amigration%3Aoauth1&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Every token I've tried returns a 400 error:

```
{   "error" : "invalid_token",   "error_description" : "Either the token is invalid or we could not decode it." }
```

I've made this call using both requests-oauthlib and postman, with the same result.

Is there anything apparent I might be doing incorrectly?